# problems in application when changing its package name

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to application development, it turns out that I have shared the template of an android application.

but it gives me the following problem when I make the change of the packname, (I also make the change in the build.gradle:app , I check the manifest and everything is fine, I have cleaned and rebuilt the project and I have cleared the cache and restarted the android studio ) but it gives me the following problem, once I have compiled the application I pass it to my cell phone but when I open it the application closes and does not open, it does not work.

Note: but if I don't change the packname the application works very well

build.gradle:
`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    //this to copied
}

def API_KEY = '"' + ApiKey + '"' ?: '"Api Key Not Found"'
def LOGIN_KEY = '"' + LoginKey + '"' ?: '"Login Key Not Found"'
def REG_KEY = '"' + RegKey + '"' ?: '"SignUp Key Not Found"'
def U_PROFILE_KEY = '"' + UprofileKey + '"' ?: '"Profile Key Not Found"'
def FP_KEY = '"' + FpKey + '"' ?: '"Forget P Key Not Found"'
def U_POINTS_KEY = '"' + UpointsKey + '"' ?: '"Update Points Key Not Found"'
def RP_KEY = '"' + RpKey + '"' ?: '"Reset P Key Not Found"'
def UD_KEY = '"' + UdKey + '"' ?: '"Update Points Key Not Found"'
def ADMIN_SETTINGS_KEY = '"' + ASettingsKey + '"' ?: '"Admin Settings Key Not Found"'
def GAME_SETTINGS_KEY = '"' + GSettingsKey + '"' ?: '"Game Settings Key Not Found"'
def REDEEM_SETTINGS_KEY = '"' + RSettingsKey + '"' ?: '"Redeem Settings Key Not Found"'
def APPS_SETTINGS_KEY = '"' + AppsSettingKey + '"' ?: '"Apps Settings Key Not Found"'
def VIDEO_SETTINGS_KEY = '"' + VideoSettingKey + '"' ?: '"Apps Settings Key Not Found"'
def VISIT_SETTINGS_KEY = '"' + VisitSettingKey + '"' ?: '"Visit Settings Key Not Found"'
def STRING = 'String'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'ApiKey', API_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'LoginKey', LOGIN_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'RegKey', REG_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'UprofileKey', U_PROFILE_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'FpKey', FP_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'UpointsKey', U_POINTS_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'RpKey', RP_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'UdKey', UD_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'ASettingsKey', ADMIN_SETTINGS_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'GSettingsKey', GAME_SETTINGS_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'RSettingsKey', REDEEM_SETTINGS_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'AppsSettingKey', APPS_SETTINGS_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'VideoSettingKey', VIDEO_SETTINGS_KEY
        }
        each {type ->
            type.buildConfigField STRING, 'VisitSettingKey', VISIT_SETTINGS_KEY
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1' //1.3.0
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3' //2.1.2
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation files('../libs/unity-ads.aar')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2' //4.13
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0' //1.4.0
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3' // 1.1.2
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0' //3.3.0
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'

    //sceen Size
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    //rootbear
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.6.0'

    //Spin
    implementation 'com.github.mmoamenn:LuckyWheel_Android:0.3.0'
    //scratch
    implementation 'in.codeshuffle.scratchcardlayout:ScratchCardLayout:1.0.8'


    //activityLifeCycle
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'


    //multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'//1.1.1
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    //:Lottie
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.0" //3.4.0


    //InApp Update
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'

    //Ads Network
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.9.1'
    implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:facebook-adapter:6.11.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier'

    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


    //Chrome Tab:
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"

    //SweetAlert
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'//1.5.1
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.61"



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'applovin-quality-service'
applovin {
    apiKey "...."
}
```

`

Manifest

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app"
    tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.Ad_ID" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.app.App"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        tools:targetApi="n">

        <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key"
            android:value="@string/APPLOVIN_SDK_KEY"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.VisitActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.InstallActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.AppsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.GiftCardActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.WatchAndEarnActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.GameLoader"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.GameActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.QuizActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.CaptchaActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.PrivacyActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.SpinActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.ScratchActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <service
            android:name="com.example.app.services.PointsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.example.app.services.UpdateDateService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.example.app.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`

I change the build.gradle:app , I check the manifest and everything is fine, I have cleaned and rebuilt the project and I have cleared the cache and restarted the android studio. what I hope is that it works with another packname

Comment: Have you also renamed the package directory from your project?

Comment: delete the application and clear the cash of the application on a device before installing the new one